# Adding MQTT using LWIP and SPI->Ethernet chip enc424j600 on STM32F4 target

Tags: mqtt, stm32f4, lwip

I'm trying to use MQTT on STM32F4 target using lwip library.
the order of the layers, as I understand it is:
MQTT->TCP/IP->Ethernet->Netif(network interface)

In an ideal world, STM32 has everything to support all these layers but the challenge here is that  the ethernet part is handled by another chip ENC424j600.

STM32F4 -- (SPI) --> ENC424j600
The code works well on Modbus mode and the idea is to switch it to MQTT.

From my understanding I should change the lwip library to be able to

| ------STM32F4 ---------------|-----ENC424j600-------|

| MQTT----->TCP/IP--SPI---> ETHERNET->NETIF--|

Am I in the right path ?
any advices, recommandation is highly welcome :)

I simply tried to use [mqtt example](https://github.com/lwip-tcpip/lwip/blob/master/contrib/examples/mqtt/mqtt_example.c) from lwip as it is to connect but it is not working for me !